# "How's keen to do X" - what's the story?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I have checked a few idiom places and general google, but found only usages of this construct, not any explanations.

Is this a silly corruption of "Who's keen", or is there something more interesting going on here?

Does it express anything other than "Who's keen" informally?

P.S. Check out the [occurrences on the internet](http://goo.gl/Xk0Zs) - doesn't really look like "how keen are you", and the first few instances occur in otherwise more or less well spelled contexts. In fact, it looks a bit like how "ask" turns into "axe" with some people...

Comment: It makes no sense.

Comment: Well, probably someone's asking the exact level of "keenness" to do X... but I agree, something's wrong here.

Comment: This looks like the kind of bastardization you see on message boards and in chat rooms. Simple misspelling on teh Internetz.

Comment: It sounds like a corruption of "How keen are you to..."

Comment: Hmmm, to me they sound like honest mistakes and were meant as *who's keen* (and [here](http://www.fordforums.com.au/showthread.php?t=11258870) it is even corrected by poster).

Comment: Looks like mostly Australian and New Zealand results on that Google search, so it's most likely a regionalism. I've certainly never encountered it in the States.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the examples from your search link, it appears that it simply a misspelling that isn't getting picked up by spellcheckers. *How's* is a valid contraction:

> How's he doing?

And is an easy enough to explain error with typical English format keyboards. The `w` is typed with your left hand and the `ho` is typed with your right. If your right hand jumps the gun, you get `how` instead of `who`. This is pure speculation, but it does seem like the uses were simply intended to be *who's*:

> How's keen for a seafood & drinking extravaganza of a weekend!
>
> At this stage I'm going solo so anyone how's keen would be good to meat up, could even meat in tairua as in there all weekend.

And so on.

Comment: Some of the cases are probably autocorrect errors. If instead of *who* you type *hwo* (swapping a pair of adjacent letters), that might be autocorrected to *how* instead of *who*.